# Speeding up pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy()

Tags: python, pandas

Is there any way of speeding up the function above? On my system, converting a dataframe with 50,000 rows and 11 columns is taking 200 ms. The rest of the code is vectorized, so this is the  one line that is taking the bulk of the time.

Comment: i'd suggest converting each column independently to a numpy array, which will be much faster than converting the entire array. now how u would compute each of them and if it is worth it... hmmm ... ur call